# How to get collection of document from mongodb cursor?

Tags: mongodb, rust, bson

I have the following code which should return a list of documents from **mongodb**.

```
struct Vehicle{
    id: String,
    name: String
}

pub async fn list_all() -> Vec<Vehicle>{
    let mongodb = connection_bd::connection_mongodb().await;
    let mongodb_collection = mongodb.collection("Vehicle");
    let result = mongodb_collection.find(None, None).await; //result: Result<Cursor<Document>, Error>
    let cursor = match result { //cursor: Cursor<Document>
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(_) => return vec![]
    };
    //...
}
```

I can't finish the code because I don't know how to convert `Cursor<Document>` to `Vec<T>`, it's my first time seeing `Cursor<Document>` and I don't know what it is.

**Updated**
Error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\vehicle_repo.rs:77:40
   |
77 |   pub async fn list_all() -> Vec<Vehicle>{
   |  ________________________________________^
78 | |     let mongodb = connection_bd::connection_mongodb().await;
79 | |     let mongodb_collection = mongodb.collection("Vehicle");
...  |
84 | |     };
85 | | }
   | |_^ expected struct `Vec`, found `()`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Vec<Vehicle>`
           found unit type `()`
```

Comment: The error you get is simply because you don't return anything at the end of the function.

Comment: @kmdreko if that's why I want to return a `vec<Vehicle>` through the **cursor** variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mongodb `Cursor` implements `Stream` from the [`futures` crate](https://crates.io/crates/futures). This is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.rs/mongodb/1.2.1/mongodb/struct.Cursor.html):

> Additionally, all the other methods that a [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.14/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) has are available on `Cursor` as well. This includes all of the functionality provided by [`StreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.14/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html), which provides similar functionality to the standard library `Iterator` trait. For instance, if the number of results from a query is known to be small, it might make sense to collect them into a vector:
>
> ```
> let results: Vec<Result<Document>> = cursor.collect().await;
> ```

I would actually recommend using the `try_collect()` function from the [`TryStreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.14/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html) trait to get a `Result<Vec<Document>>` instead. Then you can use `unwrap_or_else()` to return the list. You should also use the `collection_with_type()` method to get the collection so that your results will be automatically deserialized to the proper type instead of just `Document` (just make sure it implements `Debug`, `Serialize` and `Deserialize`).

Here's a working sample

```
use futures::TryStreamExt;
use mongodb::Client;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Vehicle {
    id: String,
    name: String,
}

async fn list_all() -> Vec<Vehicle> {
    let client = Client::with_uri_str("mongodb://example.com").await.unwrap();
    let database = client.database("test");
    let collection = database.collection_with_type::<Vehicle>("vehicles");
    let cursor = match collection.find(None, None).await {
        Ok(cursor) => cursor,
        Err(_) => return vec![],
    };

    cursor.try_collect().await.unwrap_or_else(|_| vec![])
}
```

Comment: A question. Is it `Document` = `bson::Document` ?, I get an error: `collect()` is not recognized in the **cursor** variable. : "method cannot be called on `mongodb::Cursor` due to unsatisfied trait bounds"

Comment: Can you include the full error in the original question? I think I know what the problem is but I can't be sure.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more demonstrative.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem efficiently, but do you think it works with a `dto_struct` that has fewer fields? Anyway, the original problem is already solved, once again thanks.